# How to switch to mercury-free Xenon HID bulbs?

Tags: electrical, headlight, volvo, hid

The vehicle is a Volvo XC90 year 2003, from UK.

It uses Xenon HID headlamps, with D1S bulbs, which use a small amount of mercury. I would like to switch to mercury-free bulbs, like D3S or similar, how to achieve this in this vehicle?

I know the D1 work at 85V, but the mercury-free HID lamps (D3, D4, D5, D8) work at 42V, is there a compatible ballast available which will make this work in this vehicle without other modifications?

Comment: Seems like a lot of work... I would just replace the existing, see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/55076/10976

Comment: @SolarMike I have my reasons to absolutely want to switch to mercury-free bulbs. If not possible, I'd have to switch to old non-xenon H7 or whatever else is mercury-free. Because of environmental restrictions at the location where the car is to be used in the future, it's absolutely unacceptable for even the tiniest amount of mercury to be in the vehicle in any form.